# Find Date I registered to Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I want to find when exactly I registered on Facebook. How can I do it?

p.s., I must tell you that I **deleted** my Facebook **confirmation mail**!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to wait for the new [Facebook Timeline](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline), when Facebook rolls this out to the public you will be able to do the following

[image: Joined Facebook]

Just select the timeline on the right and click the earliest year. In my case 2005.

Comment: Does not work anymore. Earliest year is my birth year. And between my first post and my birth year there is no "Joined Facebook" message.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your Facebook account settings (from the `Account` dropdown on the top right side of the page) and click `Learn More` under `Download Your Information`. Click on `Download`. You will be asked to verify your account. After Facebook collects all of your data, you will be emailed with a link to download a history of *all* your Facebook data, ever. Download the archive and open the main page. Click on your wall, and scroll down to the very bottom. It should tell you when your first post was, which will be about when you joined Facebook.

[image: fb download]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this information is available.  Well it's certainly not made available through any of the [Developer API's](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

As a rough estimate:

- Look at when you first uploaded your profile picture
- You could install this app [Status Statistics](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=8974467420)  It allows you to search through your status updates by month and year.  Bit tedious and not an exact sign up date

Hope this helps

Comment: @Berry I myself think about profile picture but the problem is that many month I didn't pic any photo for my profile. and Also I see some app that "who join first or joined before you" but when some of my friend run this app it tell different date for my(and also other) registration time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile and keep clicking the Older button/link until you get to the `{Name} joined Facebook.` entry.

Or use this [sadly useful](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=131308403549094) Facebook app.

Comment: The *{Name} joined Facebook* entry doesn't show any date.

Comment: @mark I think you have to hover over it.

Comment: Hovering doesn't do anything.  However I see that if you Inspect Element (from the Chrome context menu over the entry) there is a `pub_time` buried in there with a Unix timestamp, which seems to translate to the desired time.